# How to know for sure if FastCGI is being used to run php scripts

Tags: php, iis, iis-7, fastcgi

I have a hosted site and I'm having trouble configuring Joomla (running Joomla + php + mySQL on IIS7 + win server 2008). I have a similar configuration running on a local machine (Joomla + php + mySQL on IIS7 + vista x64), so I was at least able to follow instructions showed in various tutorials on how to set this up.

This symptom with the hosted site is that I can't turn on any SEO settings in Joomla (not even the first setting, "Search Engine Friendly URLs"). I get either 404 (file not found) or the URL appears correctly rewritten but it's always the home page's content that is displayed. I had a similar issue on my home machine and it turns out to have been because I wasn't using FastCGI to host php, so I decided to investigate that on the hosted site.

Anyway, I noticed in the web.config file of the directory hosting joomla on the hosted site the following line:

```
<add name="Plesk_Handler_3522909676" path="*.php" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="c:\program files (x86)\parallels\plesk\additional\pleskphp5\php5isapi.dll" resourceType="Either" />
```

From past experience, I know that php has some issues when not running under fastCGI. I noticed the web.config in the root folder used the following line instead:

```
<add name="Plesk_Handler_0286090609" path="*.php" verb="*" modules="CgiModule" scriptProcessor="c:\program files (x86)\parallels\plesk\additional\pleskphp5\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" />
```

I copied that in the web.config in the joomla directory, and got different behavior... but still not working. If I load a .php file in the joomla directory that runs phpInfo(), under Server API it says CGI/FastCGI . Is that **positive confirmation** that FastCGI is being used? Why does the handler in the web config point to modules="CgiModule" instead of modules="FastCgiModule" (I'm not even sure that exists, but I just find the mention of CgiModule suspicious).

It's a hosted site, so as far as I know I don't have access to ApplicationHost.config file...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here's a simple test:

1. Create a phpinfo.php file with

```
 <?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

inside;

2. Request http://yoursite.com/phpinfo.php/foobar?foo=bar
3. Check the output of phpinfo and look for _SERVER["REQUEST_URI"].

If this variable is missing, then CGI is used. If the variable is present and correctly set to /phpinfo.php/foobar?foo=bar, then either ISAPI or FastCGI is used. Look near the top of the output for Server API; it should be set to either ISAPI (which means ISAPI is being used) or CGI/FastCGI (which means FastCGI is being used, since we already ruled out CGI).

Comment: $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] may show up correctly in both CGI and FastCGI and the Server API may show 'CGI/FastCGI' for both CGI and FastCGI.

One difference is that in FastCGI $_SERVER["REDIRECT_HANDLER"] might show php-fastcgi , but that too does not confirm that "FastCGI" is being used since "php-fastcgi" is just a variable name used in the configuration file.

Comment: @Jimmy, This answer is in very much [need for citations](http://xkcd.com/285). Also, the method you describe sounds a bit *hacky*, is there a better and more robust way to determine the settings directly?

Comment: @Pacerier It worked for me, and apparently for many other people. I could not find a better way, but feel free to post a "better and more robust" answer if you have one. I came up with it myself, hence no citation.

Comment: @Jimmy, The question is asking "how to know for sure if FastCGI is being used to run php scripts", which means the people on this page have no means to verify if your answer is indeed working as stated or not. Hence I said **citation needed**. Once an answer reaches +8 votes other people'll just upvote without thinking or really trying. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1181327/632951

Answer (score 6):

php_sapi_name()  or PHP_SAPI, both work.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php

```
<?php
    if (php_sapi_name() != 'cgi-fcgi'){
        echo 'I knew fastcgi wasn\'t working.';
    }else{
        echo 'Holy crap, something worked for once.';
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Gregor this seems a great simple solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can use (on centos) `apachectl -M`, you'll show what modules are enabled:

```
apachectl -M:

file_cache_module (shared)
mem_cache_module (shared)
version_module (shared)
fastcgi_module (shared)
```

Comment: Works on Ubuntu too, though I had to use sudo

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the checking `\_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` didn't work for me. Using **CGI** or **FastCGI**, it always displayed `/phpinfo.php/foobar?foo=bar`.

Neither did seeing if `Server API = CGI/FastCGI` was set - that only tells you what interfaces the compiled version of php supports, not what is being used. However, I found another method that may work more reliably.

Plonk a file in place called **phpinfo.php** containing the text: `<? php phpinfo(); ?>`

Check for the variable `\_ENV["REDIRECT_HANDLER"]`:
If it is set to `php5-fastcgi` (or something else fastcgi-ish) the request most probably went through **FastCGI**. If it is set to `application/x-httpd-php` (or I assume something other than the above), you are using **CGI**.

However, a surefire way is by running a little test.  You need the `ab` (Apache Bench) tool for this.
Both with and without CGI, run this from another machine:

```
ab -c 100 -n 1000 http://yourdomain.com/path/phpinfo.php
```

Check the line `Time taken for tests:`. On my box at least, accessing my VPS over a 1.3Mbps ADSL connection, FastCGI completely maxed it out, while with CGI was only able to fill half of it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should see a referenced  to it from

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Server API = CGI/FastCGI

Comment: But is that for sure? My host says that they don't support FastCGI; the web.config above says they're using CGI, not FastCGI; and yet, I still see Server API = CGI/FastCGI in phpinfo()

Answer (score 0):

Joomla creates a .htaccess file with rewrite rules in it to enable search engine friendly URLs. If you're using Apache you will need to have to set "AllowOverride FileInfo" for the directory containing your joomla installation. If you are using IIS you will need a module such as IISModRewrite. Here are instructions for this: [http://www.micronovae.com/ModRewrite/articles/SEFJoomla.html]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure things are set up initially to where the script fails completely when fastcgi isn't running.  Then you'll know, when it works, that fastcgi daemon is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
/**
 * return phpinfo() results as an array
 *
 * @credit http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php#106862
 * @param void
 * @return array
 */
function phpinfo_array(){
    ob_start();
    phpinfo();
    $info_arr = array();
    $info_lines = explode("\n", strip_tags(ob_get_clean(), '<tr><td><h2>'));
    $cat = 'general';
    foreach($info_lines as $line){
        preg_match('/<h2>(.*)<\/h2>/', $line, $title) ? $cat = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', strtolower(trim($title[1]))) : null;
        if(preg_match('/<tr><td[^>]+>([^<]*)<\/td><td[^>]+>([^<]*)<\/td><\/tr>/', $line, $val)){
            $subcat = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', strtolower(trim($val[1])));
            $info_arr[$cat][$subcat] = $val[2];
        } elseif(preg_match('/<tr><td[^>]+>([^<]*)<\/td><td[^>]+>([^<]*)<\/td><td[^>]+>([^<]*)<\/td><\/tr>/', $line, $val)){
            $subcat = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', strtolower(trim($val[1])));
            $info_arr[$cat][$subcat] = array('local' => $val[2], 'master' => $val[3]);
        }
    }
    return $info_arr;
}


// output proper response code
$phpinfo = phpinfo_array();
$configure = (@isset($phpinfo['general']['configure_command'])) ?: null;

// properly account for FastCGI
if ($configure && preg_match('/--enable-fastcgi/', $configure)){
    // fastcgi response
    header('Status: 403 Access is forbidden');
} else {
    // http response
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Access is forbidden');
}
```

Comment: How does the script work and What does the script do?