# PHP Upload progress

Tags: php, file-upload, progress

After 3 whole days of testing, researching and failing I need your help please on this one.

I have this HTML form

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload_target" >
    <input type="hidden" name='<?php echo ini_get("session.upload_progress.name"); ?>"' value="myUploadProgress">
    <input type="file" name="myfile" id="file1" style="display:none">
    <button id="browse-button">Browse</button>
    <input id="update-button" class="disabled" type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Update" />
</form>
```

and I separated my php in to 2 steps:

1. upload.php - posting the form

   ```
   <?php
       session_start();

       getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

       chdir('/tmp');

       $destination_path = getcwd();

       $result = 0;

       $target_path = $destination_path . '/' .basename( $_FILES['myfile']['name']);

       if(@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
           $result = 1;
       }

       sleep(1);
   ?>
   ```
2. upload_status.php - fired by an ajax request on 1000ms interval

   ```
   <?php

       print_r($_SESSION);

   ?>
   ```

for some reason I keep getting $_SESSION as empty and I expected to get $_SESSION["upload_progress_myUploadProgress"] (or something else) as array of vars of my current upload.

Things that I have checked and already in my php.ini

- file_uploads: On
- post_max_size: 2G
- upload_max_filesize: 2G
- output_buffering: off
- session.upload_progress.cleanup: On
- session.upload_progress.enabled: On
- session.upload_progress.freq: 1%
- session.upload_progress.min_freq: 1
- session.upload_progress.name: PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
- session.upload_progress.prefix: upload_progress_

Comment: As I understood from [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php) I should get the upload progress as a key in session while the file is uploading. I don't think I need to do any set for $_SESSION

Comment: Ah i see, well did you read the comments below at the link you provided: The web server's request buffering has to be disabled or  this feature doesn't work, when your webserver is runnig PHP via FastCGI etc, etc. What php version are you using?

Comment: It is currently off, sorry I didn't mention it in my question

Comment: This may help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21703081/php-upload-progress-in-php-5-4-is-not-working-session-variables-not-set?rq=1

Comment: How can I check if i'm using PHP via FastCGI ?

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609044/how-to-know-for-sure-if-fastcgi-is-being-used-to-run-php-scripts

Comment: ok, everything is correct according to [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21703081/php-upload-progress-in-php-5-4-is-not-working-session-variables-not-set?rq=1) you gave me, weird!!!

Comment: Try adding `session_start();` in upload_status.php  before the `print_r`